# MySQL queries taking longer when response is empty

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, json, express

I'm building my first website using Node.js as the webserver and fetch to request to the server. When the MySQL database is run from localhost, my requests take less than 30ms each and there are no issues with the webpage. However, when the server is hosted somewhere else, I get very long response times ONLY when the resulting data from the query returns '[].' I'm trying to figure out why this would be the case only when requesting from a non-localhost database (or why this is happening in general).

See the difference in response times between these two links:

{ link removed }

{ link removed }

You'll see that the one which returns '[]' takes significantly longer than the other.

Here's the serverside code used:

```
    router.get('/getgames/:matchid/:season', (req, res) => {
    let sql = `SELECT * FROM games WHERE match_id='${req.params.matchid}' AND season='${req.params.season}'`;
    let query = db.query(sql, (err, result) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
        res.end(JSON.stringify(result));
    });
});
```

I don't think it's necessary to include the clientside code because the request takes just as long when it's put into the URL bar.

It's also important to note that the tables being accessed have less than 10 rows, so I don't think indexing/posting my explains would actually fix this problem (or would it??).

Edit: I've added a covering index to the 'games' table, and the query is still just as slow.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You should first connect to this mysql instance and perform both queries, check if they indeed have different response times.

Comment: @enapupe you bring up an interesting point... When the queries are performed via phpMyAdmin there is no real difference in execution time (both ~0.0005 ms). Would this mean that the issue lies in the response handling?

Comment: My first try would be replacing that `stringify(result)` with a hardcoded empty array `[]` and see what happens. But I have no idea what's happening. Seems like how node/express is playing that end of connection. The header seems to arrive ASAP, just the body is being delayed for some reason

Comment: Try replacing that `end` with `send`, and searching about `keep-alive`. Seems like node is waiting on something before sending the body and closing the connection

Comment: @enapupe I actually did already try replacing stringify with a hardcoded array, and that did not change anything. However, I did some research about keep-alive and by using res.set("Connection", "close") after res.end, the weird 5 second delay is eliminated (when using the url bar). Yet, none of my fetch requests (with this res.set afterwards) from within the website work and return 503 error code. hmm... Is there a way I can disable keep-alive by default?

Comment: @enapupe disregard the last thing I said. Within my express app .use setHeader's, I added the line res.setHeader('Connection,' 'close') and this seems to fix the issue completely. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction. You can add an answer if you would like and I'll select it. Thx a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason I'm not sure of, node seems to be waiting for keep-alive to be closed before sending that empty array body. Disabling keep-alive mitigates this issue, see https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_server_keepalivetimeout (the default timeout of keep-alive is 5s)

I suppose having a longer body overcomes this issue, that's why it's returning immediately for sets with actual sql results.